# CSS affects element in wrong section

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have been working on this website for awhile, I have run into a few problems but many of them were just small mess ups.

Now I just can not figure out what is going on here.

http://goo.gl/oEuoU5

If you look at the top text that says "Start Growing Your Business Today", you can see it has some padding.

Now if you look at in with the element inspector, you can see that the style comes from this CSS

```
.home #pricing h1, h2, h3 {

    padding: 1em;

}
```

But the problem is, that header is not in the #pricing section. So I cannot understand why it is being styled.

I have tried a few things like

```
 #pricing h1, h2, h3 {

    padding: 1em;

}
```

or

```
.pricing h1, h2, h3 {

    padding: 1em;

}
```

but nothing seems to work. I have even tried seeing if I messed up in the document flow but I cannot find any problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your link takes you to http://bizzet.co, and I don't see any text like "Start Growing Your Business Today." Is the link correct?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that, updated the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pricing h1, #pricing h2, #pricing h3 {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This should do the trick. When seperating classnames by a coma, make sure to specify all subclasses / parentclasses.

The element is therefore styled because after the first coma you only specified h2 and h3 so it styles all appearances in DOM.

Comment: '*hug*'  -- It's always some dumb mistake. You have taught me well. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem, always glad to lend people a second pair of eyes for catching nasty mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this undesired styling because you are not using the correct syntax for styling multiple items within the same elements.

This will produce what you are trying to achieve:

```
#pricing .home h1, 
#pricing .home h2, 
#pricing .home h3{

    padding: 1em;

}
```

The way you have have it, you are styling `h1` within the element with `id = "pricing"`, then `h2` and `h3` within the whole document.